# Constraints and size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a view installed for only `W:Compact H:Regular` size classes. In my UIViewController I have a state that affects constraints of this view (if state is `YES` I add new constraints with 1000 priority, if `NO`, I remove them).

If iPhone is already in portrait orientation and view is onscreen, then this works perfectly. But if I change the state to `YES` in landscape orientation, the application crashes (because the view has not superview at all at this moment).

So I want to apply changes to constraints when device rotates.

But when `-willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:` and `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` methods are called my view is still not in view hierarchy.

And `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method is deprecated, so I don't want to use it.

When should I add new constraints to view to apply `YES` state, when device rotates?

**UPD.** I don't know how bad is this solution but after some investigations of `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` protocol I've come to this code:

```
- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)([coordinator transitionDuration] * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateState];
    });
}
```